# how to keep datatype when substracting day from date/time column in SAS

Tags: date, datetime, sas, proc-sql

My question is really simple, hope someone deigns to answer!.

Being very to new SAS, the date and its formats really is confusing me.

I have timestamp column from which  I need to substract 2 days while keeping its datatype

The value of the column is "2022-04-20-19.37.57.714699"
What I need is "2022-04-18-19.37.57.714699"
When I try this I get number datatype:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE my_table AS 
SELECT 
cust_id,query_date, (query_date)-2 as calc_date
 FROM other_table
;quit;
```

I try format,datetime function, but ended up with "Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order"

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing like a date or time data type in SAS. They are just numeric, to which you might have associated a format to specify how to print them. Compare it to a numeric for length specified in cm and another one in km. If you want to subtract the one from the other, you need to convert one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the QUERY_DATE variable is numeric and has datetime values in it (the number of seconds since 1960) then you can use the [INTNX() function](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_035/ds2ref/n1mtvizfg1y0g9n1wslqgjxseh0i.htm) with the DTDAY interval to adjust the value by two days. To keep the same time of day use SAME for the alignment parameter.

```
intnx('dtday',query_date,-2,'same')
```

Alternatively you could just subtract 48 hours worth of seconds from the value.

```
query_date -2*'24:00:00't
```

If you want the values to display in a human readable way then attach any of the many datetime formats, such as DATETIME to the new variable.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS 
  SELECT cust_id,query_date
       , intnx('dtday',query_date,2,'same') as calc_date format=datetime20.
  FROM other_table
;
```

If the variable is just a string then you cannot subtract from strings.  You will have to convert the strings into numbers to perform arithmetic.  You probably have too many decimal places for SAS datetime informats/formats to replicate (and perhaps to be uniquely stored in a floating point value) so just convert the date part and then append back the rest to keep the same time of day. Since dates are stored as number of days you can just subtract the 2 days using normal subtraction.

```
put(input(query_date,yymmdd10.)-2,yymmdd10.)||substr(query_date,11)
```

Comment: Im sorry I didnt specify, its datatype is character with length of 26.

Comment: Showed how to regenerate a string for a date two days earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. The first issue to tackle is converting the date string into a sas datetime. The `input()` function with the `anydtdtm.` informat accomplishes that with a small caveat as seen in the output.

```
data test;
date_txt = '2022-04-20-19.37.57.714699';
query_date = input(date_txt, anydtdtm.);  * convert string into sas datetime;
calc_date = intnx('dtday', query_date, -2, 's');  * backup 2 days preserving the time;
format query_date calc_date e8601dt26.6;
run;
```

| date_txt | query_date | calc_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-20-19.37.57.714699 | 2022-04-20T19:37:57.000000 | 2022-04-18T19:37:57.000000 |

The default width of the informat is 19 characters which excludes the fractional seconds, but the informat correctly converted the string into a datetime.

To attempt to capture the full width of the date string, I modified the informat to `anydtdtm26.`. However, that change resulted in an error and missing values for query_date and calc_date. Although the `anydtdtm` informat is robust with converting a wide variety of date and time formats, I suspected that the problem lies with the periods used to delimit the hours and minutes.

To correct that problem I used `prxchange()` function to replace the periods after hours and minutes with colons which are standard time componenent delimiters. That change allows the `anydtdtm` informat to properly convert the fractional seconds.

```
data test2;
date_txt = '2022-04-20-19.37.57.714699';
date_mod = prxchange('s/\./:/', 2, date_txt); * replace first 2 periods w/ colons;
query_date = input(date_mod, anydtdtm26.);  * convert string into sas datetime;
calc_date = intnx('dtday', query_date, -2, 's');  * backup 2 days preserving the time;
format query_date calc_date e8601dt26.6;
run;
```

| date_txt | date_mod | query_date | calc_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-20-19.37.57.714699 | 2022-04-20-19:37:57.714699 | 2022-04-20T19:37:57.714699 | 2022-04-18T19:37:57.714699 |

Although I used a data step to illustrate the solution the functions can also be used in a SQL statement.